# SurfaceView Crashes when returning from another activity

Tags: android, multithreading, layout, surfaceview, crash

i have a thread problem with my surfaceView, its quite common but i have not found a solution anywhere.

I use a SurfaceView as a Background in a frame layout:

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/blobmusic_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.myapp.Background
    android:id="@+id/background_blobmusic"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    ...
```

and my background class is the tipical surfaceview class, with the holder, the thread wich will call our onDraw method, etc. Some code to avoid questions (init() is called in the constructor methods):

```
    public void init() {
    ready = false;
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback( new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean retry = true;
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    bgdt.setRunning(false);
                    bgdt.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
            estrelles = new Estrelles(getResources(),getHeight());
            bgdt.setRunning(true);
            bgdt.start();
            ready = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

and my thread class (bgtd):

```
public class BGDrawThread extends Thread {
private Background view;
static final long FPS = 60;
private boolean running = false;

public BGDrawThread(Background view) {
      this.view = view;
}

public boolean isRunning() {
    return running;
}

public void setRunning(boolean run) {
      running = run;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    long ticksPS = 1000/FPS;
    long startTime;
    long sleepTime;
    //fps checker
    long contms=0;
    long lasttimecheck = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int fps=0;
    while (running) {
        if(contms>1000) {
            //souts ??
            contms=0;
            fps=0;
            lasttimecheck = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        else {
            fps++;
            contms+=System.currentTimeMillis()-lasttimecheck;
            lasttimecheck=System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        Canvas c = null;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                view.onDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
        sleepTime = ticksPS-(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        try {
            if (sleepTime > 0)
                   sleep(sleepTime);
            else
                   sleep(10);
     } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
}
```

**This works fine, until another activity comes to front and then we come back from it, that crashes.**

Here's my code of onpause/onresume methods of the class:

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Background bmbg = (Background) findViewById(R.id.background_blobmusic);
    bmbg.resumethread();
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Background bmbg = (Background) findViewById(R.id.background_blobmusic);
    bmbg.stopthread();
}
```

and the strop/resume thread in the surfaceview class:

```
    public void stopthread() {
    if(!bgdt.isAlive()) return;
    boolean retry = true;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            bgdt.setRunning(false);
            bgdt.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
public void resumethread() {
    if(ready && !bgdt.isRunning()) {
        bgdt.setRunning(true);
        bgdt.start();
    }
}
```

All help is welcome :)

EDIT: i made it  run (probably not an elegant solution, but i leave the code here):
(look at the comment below to see the other changes)

```
public void startthread() {
    if(!surfacecreated) return;
    if(threadrunning) return;
    bgdt = new BGDrawThread(this);
    bgdt.setRunning(true);
    bgdt.start();
    threadrunning = true;
}

public void stopthread() {
    boolean retry = true;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            bgdt.setRunning(false);
            bgdt.join();
            threadrunning = false;
            retry = false;

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC surface is ready for manipulations only after surfaceChanged() callback,  not surfaceCreated() ,  and surfaceChanged() is called after onResume() -  move your initialisation and thread startup there ( to surfaceChanged() )

Comment: Well it does not work. It crashes even before i can see anything of the main activity. Any other ideas?

Comment: After a while doing some tests and some research, i find out what was going on. SurfaceChanged is only called when onStop() is called, not after onPause(). From here I set a pair of control variables, surfacecreated and threadrunning, and i call startthread() in my onStart and onResume methods, and stopthread() in my onPause onResume methods. Also startthread() is called by surfacecreated.
my functions are: (edited part on main post).